# How do I download a file by doing a webClient.DownloadFile() which requires a password?

Tags: c#, http-headers, http-get

The following code is not working because it downloads the actual log-in page of the URL. Yes, the text boxes for username/password. They come down as an .xls file. It's not downloading the actual file. If I go the URL myself, it DOES download the Excel file to my computer. PLEASE NOTE - When I click on the URL, it asks for my credentials.

```
private void btnGet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) 
    {
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        client.DownloadFile("longLink", @"C:\Report.xls");
     }
}
```

Do I need to maybe provide a header with a session ID??

Comment: If you know you should have access to the file, the easiest way to get it working would be to apply your default credentials to your client. Eg, client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials; or client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

Comment: This is not the issue. There are several different people in different locations trying to access this file. If you manually click the link, it'll prompt you for your credentials. Then I put my credentials in and then it starts downloading the Excel file. I think the problem is with the cookies?

Comment: I'd suggest using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to monitor your web traffic. Find out what your computer is sending when you downdload the file using your web browser, then emulate that using your program.